There is no ping from docker to some external resources
Description of the problem
Docker-Desktop with WSL2 (Ubuntu 20.04) is installed on my Windows 10 work computer
I run the docker with the command: docker run -it --rm -p 80:80 nginx /bin/bash
In it, I want to ping the servers 192.168.10.47 and 192.168.10.6, which are available both from WSL and from my computer, but I can't do it. These addresses are not docker.
In addition to the servers I needed, I also pinged to other available resources: 10.30.1.56, 10.30.2.12 google.com, superuser.com and I got a successful result.
Thus, I can't reach only servers like 192.168.x.x.
How I tried to solve the problem:

I made sure that the ip addresses are specified correctly and there is access to them (Checked by ping on localhost and WSL).
I tried to run docker in host mode: docker run -it --rm --net=host -p 80:80 nginx/bin/bash - the problem is not solved

Additional information:

ip route in WSL


user@ist103n6:~$ ip route 
default via 172.27.208.1 dev eth0 proto kernel 
172.27.208.0/20 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 172.27.211.43


The problem is solved. It turns out that my Hyper-V adapter was on another network (screenshot 1). I changed it to 172.x.x.x (screenshot 2) and restarted the system. Everything is working now.


